# QrCode library not generating a QR Code

Tags: ios, xcode, qr-code

A QR code generating library I am using (listed here):
 https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator/blob/master/README

Is not working in my xcode project. I cant understand why but the QR code isnt being generated.

I am setting up the QR code with these 3 lines:

```
Barcode *barcode = [[Barcode alloc] init];
[barcode setupQRCode:@"hello"];
_pictureOutlet.image = barcode.qRBarcode;
```

I have also followed the readme dragging the libpng and QRDraw folders in to my project as sub directories.

[image]

what could be the issue? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I had a white background and this library does not generate a black background for anyone who makes the same silly mistake.